# How to I add a springframework/fasterxml hook for pre/post JSON serialisation?

Tags: jpa, fasterxml, spring-json

I have a JPA entity A that I want to serialize into JSON using springframework annotations.

The entity has a (non identifying) foreign key, so in the JPA, this is an object B.

1. I want our angular front-end to be able to create these entities, which means that the JSON coming from the front end needs to contain the key
2. I want to send object A to the angular front end, without pulling in the whole of object B - just the key.

I have therefore created in the JPA entity A an object b of type B and a field bKey of type String and mapped both to column B_KEY. I have marked then as being updatable false and insertable false, but JPA is still complaining that I have a duplicate column.

So, I am thinking of adding a `@Transient` property bKey which is not managed by JPA at all. This property would be populated just before serialzation to JSON, and unpacked (`bRegistry.findById(bkey)`) on deserialization.

I'd like to do this without having to write a whole serializer, which looks like it is a bit of a rabbit-hole.

Is there a `@PreJsonSerialization`  / `@PostJsonDeserialization` kind of thing in fasterxml? I haven't found it.

Failing that - what base class do I extend for use with `@JSonSerialize`? I would prefer not to have to write the serializer by hand, writing out each field in code.

Alternatively, is there a "when you convert this to JSON, just send the key columns, not the whole object"?